# how to enable monogdb authentication in windows

Tags: mongodb

How to enable monogdb authentication in windows.

```
 use admin 
 db.createUser(
{ user: "useradmin", pwd: "thepianohasbeendrinking", roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ] } )
```

added in mongod.cfg

```
#security:
     authorization: "enabled"
```

since it is windows updated the services to include --auth

```
sc config MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.exe\" --config \"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\7.0\bin\mongod.cfg\" --service --auth"
when I started the mongodb service it gave error
```

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
> request in a timely fashion.

I looked at the monogdb log the last info was of it shutting down. there is no error message  related to start up error
Is there step I am missing ?

```
metadata","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:60914","client":"conn534","doc":{"driver":{"name":"nodejs","version":"3.3.4"},"os":{"type":"Windows_NT","name":"win32","architecture":"x64","version":"10.0.22621"},"platform":"'Node.js v10.2.0, LE (unified)","application":{"name":"MongoDB Compass"}}}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.462+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23315,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Received request from Windows Service Control Manager","attr":{"code":"SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP","inShutdown":"false"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.463+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.463+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.463+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.463+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.463+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.465+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784903, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the LogicalSessionCache"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.466+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.466+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784908, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the PeriodicThreadToAbortExpiredTransactions"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784909, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicationCoordinator"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784910, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the ShardingInitializationMongoD"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784911, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Enqueuing the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.467+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784912, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Killing all operations for shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4695300, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Interrupted all currently running operations","attr":{"opsKilled":4}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":5093807, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down all TenantMigrationAccessBlockers on global shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":6529201, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Network interface redundant shutdown","attr":{"state":"Stopped"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784913, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down all open transactions"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784914, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Acquiring the ReplicationStateTransitionLock for shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.468+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":4784915, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the IndexBuildsCoordinator"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.469+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.469+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.469+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn4","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:56826","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"8e26f951-32b7-44cb-abfd-0a6baabbb0cd"}},"connectionId":4,"connectionCount":5}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.469+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.470+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.470+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.470+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.470+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684100, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.470+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"INDEX",    "id":3684101, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Finished shutting down TTL collection monitor thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.471+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.471+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.471+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784930, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down the storage engine"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.471+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22320,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down journal flusher thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.471+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22321,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Finished shutting down journal flusher thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.472+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.472+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.472+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22261,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Timestamp monitor shutting down"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.472+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20282,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Deregistering all the collections"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.473+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22317,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.473+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.473+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.473+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,use_timestamp=false,"}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.501+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":28}}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.501+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22281,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.502+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.502+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
    {"t":{"$date":"2023-11-26T05:57:17.507+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"serviceShutdown","msg":"Now exiting"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
security:
  authorization: "enabled"
```

The configuration file is a YAML file, thus the number of space characters matters!

You can also write

```
security.authorization: "enabled"
```

When you enable it in the config file, then there is no need to enable it again with the command line.